# Need help inserting multiple records from an html form using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a PHP page which generates a list of records from a table (members) in MySQL in the form of an html table. What I want to do is be able to check (using a checkbox) the records i want to work with. When I check some/all of the records, I want to add some more information (number of shares each member has) and insert those records into another table (shares). Both tables (shares & members) share a column (member_ID).

So, I need help with the following:

1. How do I code the html table to include a checkbox as well as an input field for number of shares?
2. How do I write my function which will insert a record for each checked record?

I realize this is a lot to ask so any effort in helping me with this will be much appreciated.

Here is my [erroneous] code:

HTML Form:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?action=add_shares&org_ID=<?php echo $org_ID; ?>"     id="add_shares
    <table>
    <?php foreach ($members as $members) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="member_ID" name="member_ID[]" value="'"$members['member_ID']."'" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><?php echo $members['nick_name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Click to distribute shares" />
</form>
```

Here is my function:

```
function add_share($asset_ID, $member_ID, $percent_owner) {
global $db;
$query = "INSERT INTO shares
            (asset_ID, member_ID, percent_owner)
          VALUES
            ($asset_ID, $member_ID, $percent_owner)";
$add_shares = $db->exec($query);
```

I believe I need a foreach somewhere in my function. I also think that I need to somehow collect all the checked records from the html form into an array, then use foreach to do an insert for each record in the array.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code thus far?

Comment: I have a similar need where a user has to pick from 640 cards the ones he owns. The form is created with checkboxes in a form.  I'm wondering how to write the update SQL statement to take each of the 640 card ids and insert/update into the db.  How did you code your solution?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have error checking, and assumes an equal distribution of shares.

```
// Assuming equal distribution of shares...
$percent_owner = 100 / count($_POST['member_ID']);
foreach ($_POST['member_ID'] as $member_ID) {
    add_share($_GET['org_ID'], $member_ID, $percent_owner);
}
```

I would move the `action` and `org_ID` into hidden input tags so you the PHP variables can all be accessed through the $_POST variable, but that's just me.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" id="add_shares">
    <input type="hidden" name="org_ID" value="<?php echo $org_ID; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_shares" />
    ...
<!-- in your PHP code $_GET['org_ID'] becomes $_POST['org_ID'] -->
```

Comment: For percent_owner, I want a text box in my form so that it can be a typed-in value. I want to submit the member_ID and percent_owner for each checked record.